# ASP: request.form is not returning value?

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I have following form,

```
<form action="contact_us.asp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
   <input name="firstname" type="text" id="firstname" size="30" />
   <input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" size="30" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

But when I am trying to get value of these post variables in my ASP file contact_us.asp then it returns blank. Code is below:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<%

Dim FirstName, LastName, Email, Message
FirstName = request.form("firstname")
LastName = request.form("lastname")

response.write(FirstName & "OK")

%>
```

Its returning only "OK" to me. nothing in Message variable?

Please help me and tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: ? there is no `<input name="message"/>` (or `email` for that matter) in the above HTML.

Comment: When I remove `enctype="multipart/form-data"` from HTML <from> tag then its working fine and returning value.

Comment: If you don't need to make file uploads you can remove enctype="multipart/form-data"

Comment: Have you submit button? Or show how do you force POST method?

Comment: yes, It has a "submit" HTML button. I have added it to code in the question. Please check!

Comment: @Cris: Yes I have done that to make it work. But I just want to know if we've added `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to our form then how will we retrieve values of simple text fields.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Classic ASP doesn't provide built-in support for working with `multipart/form-data. This is a surprisingly basic deficiency even for a language of ASP's venerable age, but what're you gonna do about it, move to ASP.NET? (Yes? oh. well never mind then.)

If you aren't doing file uploads, it's easiest just to stick with the default `enctype` (which is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`). The only advantage of `multipart/form-data` is that you can put file uploads in it. (Theoretically, it would also have the advantage that you can specify character encodings definitively. But no browser actually does that.)

If you do need to handle `multipart/form-data` in Classic ASP you will need to parse the incoming request body yourself, splitting it into fields and values. Or rather, more typically, use an existing library to do it*.

That library will usually provide separate interfaces for reading the uploaded files and the other form values. This completely replaces use of the Classic ASP `Request.Form` interface. Exactly where you can find it depends on the library you choose. This does mean that if you want to have a form that can respond to either `enctype` equally you have to check the type and use one of the two different interfaces.

*: There are loads. [for](http://www.pscode.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=7361&lngWId=4) [example](http://www.freeaspupload.net/). I'm not endorsing either of these as such... neither of them actually parse multiparts properly as per the standard and both seem a bit lax about filename security (*never* store a file under the user-submitted filename! security disaster!). But that seems to be par for the course for ASP upload scripts. At least, unlike many, they're not asking money for them.

Comment: It does support it but you have to read the raw byte data - `Request.BinaryRead()`.

Answer (score 2):

I found by removing `enctype` completely (which defaults to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`) from the form tag that `Request.Form("SomeInputTagId")` worked fine with `method="post"`. I also didn't need to install any third party readers. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Remove that from the code and see if it works.  The `form-data enctype` is used for uploading data, for example image files.  You need to access the form elements slightly differently if you use that `enctype`.

If you are uploading data, then the ASP object you are using (for example `ASP Upload`) will have functions to access form fields.  `Request.form("")` wont work.

Accessing the form values would be along the lines of:

```
Set yourUploadComponent = CreateObject("Your.UploadComponentClassString")
sFormValue = yourUploadComponent.Form.Item("txtName").Value
```

You will need to read the objects documentation.