# Request.form('txtname') is blank

Tags: asp-classic

I have a form containing table. I one of cell I have a HTML text control.
The form method defined as POST & on action the page itself.
When I use

```
Dim myVar=Request.form('txtName')
```

The value I print in label coming blank.
Whereas when i view in firebug it showing post value in textbox correctly.

Please tell where am I missing. Why am not getting value in span.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649799/asp-request-form-is-not-returning-value... got the answer here. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Try

```
Dim myVar
myVar = Request.form("txtName")
```