# Active Server Pages error 'ASP 0107' Data size too large

Tags: asp-classic

This error is returned from a web page when POSTing to .asp page.

Event Viewer has more information about it:

> "File path/file.asp Data size too large. Size of data being sent in
>   the request is over the allowed limit.."

Regular form is posted with a few dozen of text fields with total request size under 2KB.

Also it works most of times, fails only once in a while.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3661121/3748030) may help.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this had nothing to do with posting large data to page. Request size was small.

The reason was that one of the COM components which was called from the page had infinite loop on certain conditions.