# Retrieve ajax formData on classic asp page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vbscript, asp-classic, form-data

I'm sending data with ajax to my asp classic page - with new FormData()
and my alert shows [object FormData] so it should be right?
But Im trying to display the variables "folderName" from my asp page in my success alert but it is not showing anything.

So how do I receive the formData on my asp page?

This is what I have now

```js
var formData = new FormData($$(page.container).find('#pdffile')[0]);
formData.append("folderName", "manmade");
myApp.alert(formData); //this shows [object FormData]

$$.ajax({
method: 'POST',
url: 'dokument/dokument2.asp',
//processData: false,
//contentType: false,
enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
data: formData,
       success: function (data) {
           myApp.alert(data)//I get nothing in the alert?
        }

        });

        return false;
});
```

and in my asp page I just use request.form!?

```
<%
folderName = request.form("folderName")
%>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
</head>
<body>
    <%=folderName%>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know why I can´t receive the variable on my asp page?
Any input really appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If the purpose of dokument2.asp is to populate a js alert, is html (rather than plaintext or xml) the correct format for the output?

Comment: I don't see an evident problem with the code, have you verified you are in fact sending the data you can do that using firebug, developer tools in  or fiddler ?

Comment: John, if I send it with just - data:some variable, then I get it in the alert but not if I use formData?

Comment: Rafael, Im not sure, Im looking in the network inspector in safari and it says it has send 459 B, but Im not sure? Im not so sure what to look for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send FormData objects with Ajax-requests in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery)

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3661121/1682881. You cannot use `Request.Form` when the enctype is `multipart/form-data`

Answer (score 0):

try this for second asp file

---

```
<%
folderName = request.form("folderName")
%>
<%= folderName%>
```

---

line with

```
enctype: 'multipart/form-data'
```

in first file have to be removed. You can not access multipart/form-data from asp without special libs...

Comment: DimaSun, no it is not working. No matter what I do I get noting in my alert on the asp page. Im trying to upload a .pdf file and save it on my server, but when I test to just get the folderName variable in the alert I get nothing?
I just don´t know where I go wrong?

Comment: Thats true you need a component to upload i remember one was name freeaspupload idk is still there

Comment: Rafael. Ok, I have a component called aspsmartupload, and if I post the form without ajax, then I can save the .pdf file, but if I do it with ajax it is not working, it is not finding the the form field with the file.
Im using mySmartUpload.files.item(1).saveas("path/filename") when I post without ajax and then it saves it, but not with ajax?

Comment: Claes, did you ever figure this out?  I am doing with non file upload but the ajax is sending back in a format that the request.form is not populated.  I think it it content type related, but I cannot change that since it is a set script I cannot control.  Any feedback would be appreciated!!!  thank you :)