# ASP Classic - Request.Form data has no value

Tags: html, forms, http, asp-classic

I'm new to ASP. I'm using MSWindows Server 2008 x86 6.0.6002 to make simple "PersonalInformation" page.

Even though this is pathetic, please do not downvote.

But I've got a problem that cannot get value from `Request.Form` data.

Implementation here on **TestHtml.html & TestAsp.asp**.

**TestHtml.html**

```
<html>
<title>MultiPart FormData Test</title>
<header></header>
<body>
<form action="http://10.21.56.101/Test/TestAsp.asp" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="MPDFTest" id="MPDFTest">
Name : <input name="ST_Name" type="text" id="ST_Name"/>
Sex : <input name="ST_Sex" type="text" id="ST_Sex"/>
Age : <input name="ST_Age" type="text" id="ST_Age"/>
Height : <input name="ST_Height" type="text" id="ST_Height"/>
SData : <input name="ST_SData" type="file" id="ST_SData"/>
<input name="ST_SendInfo" type="submit" value="SaveData" id="ST_SendInfo"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**TestAsp.asp**

```
<%
Option Explicit
Dim miName, miSex, miAge, miHeight
miName = Request.Form("ST_Name")
miSex = Request.Form("ST_Sex")
miAge = Request.Form("ST_Age")
miHeight = Request.Form("ST_Height")

Response.Write "---- Data Check ----<br>"
Response.Write "Name : " & miName & "<br>"
Response.Write "Sex : " & miSex & "<br>"
Response.Write "Age : " & miAge & "<br>"
Response.Write "Height : " & miHeight & "<br>"

If miName = "" Or miSex = "" Or miAge = "" Or miHeight = "" Then
    Response.Write "Please check Name, Sex, Age, Height again!<br>"
Else
    Response.Write "Data Saved.<br>"
End If
%>
```

As you see, this is a simple code.
But on `TestAsp.asp`, it doesn't get value from `Request.Form` data.

I always get string **"Please check Name, Sex, Age, Height again!"**.
Why? and What's wrong on my code?

Someone please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP: request.form is not returning value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649799/asp-request-form-is-not-returning-value)

Answer (score 1):

Remove `enctype="multipart/form-data"`
And replace  `name="ST_Age` to `name="ST_Age"`, and `name="ST_Height` to `name="ST_Height"`.

To upload file use `aspupload` or `asppdf` and don't forget to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` at the beginning of the `form`

Comment: Thank you. but still get  "Please check Name, Sex, Age, Height again!". What does "beginning of the form" mean? Please give some example.