# request.form did not show value

Tags: forms, asp-classic

I try to send value CSRFToken inside a form and I try to recall it but it did not show any value, the form type is POST, in javascript the value of CSRFToken is exist but when i try to request form the value is empty

```
function OutputForm()
%>
    <form name="frmSend" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="Upload_Data_Transaksi.asp" onSubmit="return onSubmitForm();">
    <table width="500" align="center" >
    
    <tr>
        <td>
            <font size="+1"><B>Data Transaksi</B></font><br><br>    
            File : <input name="attach1" type="file" size=50><br>
        <br> 
                <input type="text" name="CSRFToken" value="<%= token %>" readonly>

                <input style="margin-top:4" type=submit value="Upload">
                 <br><br><B><font color="#FF0000" size="+1">Tipe File Harus .mdb !</font><B>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    
    </form>
<%
end function
```

```
<BODY>


<%
Dim diagnostics
if Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") <> "POST" then
    diagnostics = TestEnvironment()
    if diagnostics<>"" then
        response.write "<div style=""margin-left:20; margin-top:30; margin-right:30; margin-bottom:30;"">"
        response.write diagnostics
        response.write "<p>After you correct this problem, reload the page."
        response.write "</div>"
    else
        response.write "<div style=""margin-left:15"">"
        OutputForm()
        response.write "</div>"
    end if
else
    userauthentication()    
    response.write "<div style=""margin-left:15"">"

    response.Write request.form("CSRFToken")
    response.End
    OutputForm()
    %>
    <table width="500" align="center" > 
    <tr>
        <td> <% x = SaveFiles()
        if left(x,1)=1 then

            Response.Redirect "insert_mdb.asp?nmfile=us3r" & SESSION("User_id") & mid(x,3)
        else
        response.Write x
        end if
        %></td>
        
    </tr>
    </table>
    <%
    
    response.write "<br><br></div>"
end if

%>

<br><br>

</BODY>
```

i try to recall it in request.form("CSRFToken") but it show no value, i alert it on javascript it show the value how do i solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP: request.form is not returning value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3649799/asp-request-form-is-not-returning-value)

Comment: when I delete enctype and request form it's work but when I try to upload the file it doesn't upload a file, I need the upload works too

Comment: Please read all the answers in the linked question

Comment: I still don't understand should I use freeaspupload?

Comment: @omik what don’t you understand? To work with multipart data in Classic ASP you either have to decode and parse the binary structures yourself, use an existing custom upload class to make this easier (freeaspupload etc.) or use a 3rd party COM Component.